# Best way to store nested document in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Requirement is to store the inventory item details in db.
each merchant can have their own inventory, in this case which is the best way to store the items?

--> heavy reads and writes will come in future in those collections.

1. storing each item as individual document?

   ```
    {item1}
    {item2}...etc
   ```
2. storing all the items in one document per merchant?

   ```
   {
    "products": [{item1},{item1},{item3}...etc]
   }
   ```

scalability, performance wise which way is best, any other way to store?

in terms of reads and writes which way is better to store please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I tried with the 1st and 2nd solution and i got know 1st one is the best solution because
--> 2nd solution will not be workout due to not possible to store more than 15mb data in one document.
--> i tried with few item details with the size of 10k items in one document and the size is more than 15 mb and not able to store it, so 2nd solution will not work.